# "Just" in reported speech

Tags: adverbs, reported-speech

I have this sentence:

> "My father has just bought a new printer", he said

There is **just** word, and I don't know how the **just** word changes if I convert the original sentence to reported speech. Can I use **recently** instead? I feel using **just** is illogical.

Comment: There is a certain immediacy about *just* that doesn't obtain with *recently*. The word may bother you, as a non-native speaker, but native speakers have no trouble at all with it.

Comment: He told me that his father had just bought a new printer.

Comment: It is more like telling occurrence or change in an event which was being monitored either with or without expectation. Also, if the news came closer to the event occurring, and **recently** can't emphasize the freshness, just is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and IMHO should) still use *just*:

> He said his father had just bought a new printer.

There's nothing illogical about this; *just* is interpreted relative to the "He said", not relative to the present. We can also say, for example:

> When we got there, they had **just** left.
>
> "Where were you working in 1986?"
>   "Well, in 1986 I would have **just** graduated from diapers; so I suppose I was unemployed?"

(and so on).